# Have a different Display Value, but sort by original value DataTables jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm having a slight issue, I am using DataTables and I have the following data in a column

```
1-2
3
4
5
6
7-8
9
```

and so on. Currently, these are being treated as strings, and so the sorting is messed up. When I change their values to integers, the sorting is fine, however, I loose the information, instead of showing 1-2 it shows 1 and instead of 7-8 it shows 7 and so on.

I am wondering if I can have a "Displayed" value and a "sorting value". Making it so DataTables displays it as strings, but uses the values that I have changed into integers for sorting. It would be great it someone could help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is discussed in the DataTable [documentation](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting). It involves including the natural sorting plugin with your other JavaScript code and specifying the "sType" as "natural":

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="naturalSort.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-asc'] = function(a, b) {
        return naturalSort(a, b);
    };
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['natural-desc'] = function(a, b) {
        return naturalSort(a, b) * -1;
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                { "sType": "natural" },
                null
            ]
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: DataTables already handles the sorting. I just need it to have separate values, one for display and one for sorting.

Comment: Tried it, however, it's not entirely working.

I get the following error in my javascript console: 

`Uncaught TypeError: Property 'natural-asc' of object #<Object> is not a function jquery.dataTables.js:4038
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

Here is one of the URLs where this is present: http://phanime.com/anime/naruto-shippuden/